# C++ re-assignable const member variable

Tags: c++

In C++, suppose I have a member variable of type `Bar`, and I want to make sure only `const` methods are called on it. So then AFAIK I can declare it as a `const Bar` member variable like below:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(const Bar& b) : bar(b) {}

  void setBar(Bar& b) {
    bar = b;  // compiler complains here
  }

private:
  const Bar bar;
}
```

But I also want to be able to re-assign `bar` altogether. Is this possible to do without the compiler complaining?

Comment: setBar is a constant method?

Comment: Since assignment **is** a non-const method, this isn't possible in general. You can wrap it in a class that provides a getter returning `const Bar &`, but allows the assignment.

Comment: If you want to be able to re-assign `bar` - why make it `const`?

Comment: if bar is const then you can't change it. This is what const means if you want to be able to change it don't make it const. (Tecnicly you can say `*(Bar*(&bar))=b;` which changes the value of bar but this leads to undefined behavior.) So just don't make a member const if you want to change it

Comment: Maybe you want a `std::unique_ptr<const Bar>`. Then you can assign new instances of `Bar` to it, but you cannot call its non-`const` member functions. Though since you have unique ownership anyway, you can just make `bar` non-`const` and not call it's non-`const` member functions. It's `private` so you are fully in control of which of its member functions you call.

Comment: @BotondHorváth As you say, that is UB, so technically, you *can't* use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "trick" is to have your member data be a `std::shared_ptr<const Bar>` instead of `const Bar`; you can then re-assign the `shared_ptr` at will, but can't change `Bar` since the pointer is `const`.

```
#include <memory>

struct Bar final {};
struct Foo final
{
    //Foo(const Bar& b) : bar(b) {}
    Foo(const Bar& b) : pBar(std::make_shared<const Bar>(b)) {}

    void setBar(const Bar& b) {
        //bar = b;  // compiler complains here
        pBar = std::make_shared<const Bar>(b);
    }

private:
    //const Bar bar;
    std::shared_ptr<const Bar> pBar;
};
```

Note that `std::unique_ptr` might be better than `std::shared_ptr`, but then you've got to add copy/assignment, assuming you want those.  However, since it's a `shared_ptr` to **`const`**`Bar`, it's not all that bad.

Answer (score 3):

`const` members create more problems than they solve. If you want to make sure to only call `const` methods on `bar` but you want it not to be `const` (because you want to reassign it) then you can add another layer of encapsulation. For example:

```
struct Bar {
    void doSomething() const {}
};

struct BarHolder {
    BarHolder(const Bar& b) : bar(b) {}
    const Bar& get() {return bar;}
    void set(const Bar& b) { bar = b;}    
private:
    Bar bar;
};

class Foo {
public:
  Foo(const Bar& b) : bar(b) {}

  void doSomething() {
      bar.get().doSomething(); // <- can only call const methods
  }

  void setBar(Bar& b) {
    bar.set(b);
  }

private:
  BarHolder bar;
};
```

It didn't occur to me at first, but as mentioned in a comment, you similarly get "another layer of encapsulation" by using a `std::unique_ptr<const Bar>`, though then the object will be actually `const`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `Bar` member variable to be re-assignable, then you don't want it to be `const`. This doesn't mean you can't call the `const` member functions on it; it just means that if a competing non-`const` overload exists, it will call the non-`const` one -- for example:

```cpp
struct Bar {
    // (1)
    auto get_baz() -> Baz&;
    // (2)
    auto get_baz() const -> const Baz&; 
};

Bar bar;
const Bar cbar;

auto& b1 = bar.get_baz();  // calls (1) because bar is not const
auto& b2 = cbar.get_baz(); // calls (2) because cbar is const
```

This issue does not happen if there are no non-`const` competing overloads:

```cpp
struct Bar {
     auto get_buzz() const -> const Buzz&;
};

Bar bar;
const Bar cbar;

// These both call the one get_buzz
auto& b1 = bar.get_buzz();
auto& b2 = cbar.get_buzz();
```

If you want to explicitly force the call to the `const` overload, you just need to make sure you call it from a const-qualified object or reference instead. This can be done easily with [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)'s [`std::as_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const)

```cpp
const Baz& b = std::as_const(bar).get_baz(); // calls (2)
```

If you don't have access to C++17, then you could also just form a `const` reference to `Bar` either by using a `static_cast`, or by using a temporary `const` reference, such as:

```cpp
const Baz& b = static_cast<const Bar&>(bar).get_baz();

// or

const auto& const_bar = bar;
const Baz& b = const_bar.get_baz();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd point out is that your understanding of "const" methods is a bit off: a const method does not mean that it can modify const *members*, but that it can be called on a const instance of that class.

Eg if you have

```
class Foo { 
public:
   void method1() const { ... };
   void method2() { ... };
}
```

and then a const instance of Foo as

```
const Foo foo1;
```

then you could call

```
foo1.method1()
```

becuase method1 is const, as is foo1; but you could not call method2, because foo1 is const, and method2 is not.

That said, what you are looking for is probably the "mutable" keyword on your member: usually a const method will not allow changing any members of that class (well, because the instance of that calss is *const*!); however, you can tag individual members of the class to be "mutable", which will allow const methods to change that member.

Eg, if you have

```
class Foo { public:
  int a; 
  mutable int b;
  void method() const { ... }
}
```

Then Foo::method() would be allowed to change 'a', but not 'b'.

Once you declare a *member* of a class as const, then only the constructor can set this member.